# Library Package Documentation

Tags: package-management, development

I've seen in many packages like libutouch-geis that there is also another package with -doc suffix. Is this package the documentation of the library ? Is it possible to read it and if yes how ? If no ,the only "documentation" for libraries like utouch is the header files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, if there is a `-doc` package for a library, then yes, it is the documentation. Generally, it is also in HTML format. There's also a package `devhelp` for reading development oriented documentation. If the documentation does not appear in the `devhelp` application, then you can simply read the documentation in a browser, by opening the HTML files in a browser. Some of these packages also include man pages, rather than HTML documentation. You can simply look at the flies list of the package to determine which is the best way to read the documentation within.

Comment: Devhelp is really nice, I just installed it and I can see the documentations. Thanks for your answer :)